# Is this solar circuit connection OK?

Tags: solar-cell, solar-charge-controller, mppt

My inverter requires a 96v battery input and my MPPT solar charge controllers have a maximum battery voltage of 48v, so I connected them together like this:

Is this a bad connection? If yes, what is the alternative under the same constraints?

[image: PV array connection]

Comment: What's the specs of the panels? Connecting the 460W panels in series with the 550W panels could be a problem. For the chargers: it depends. For the batteries: if you end up with uneven charge for the two in-series sets, you could wear them out prematurely.

Comment: What's the Voc, Vmpp, Isc and Impp of the 460 and 550 W panels respectively?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to at least be able to check the balance between your battery banks, and stop the inverter's use of them if either drop below 44 V, even if you intervene manually to correct any imbalance. Imbalance could arise if one set of panels is consistently illuminated more than the other set.

Once you've bought an automatic balancer with sufficient capacity to handle any imbalanced output from the two charge controllers, you might have spent more than buying the proper controllers to go with the inverter or *vice versa*.

However, maybe the charge controllers have a simple control input to throttle back their charge output to avoid battery imbalance.

460/550 W panels in series may or may not be a problem. If the are different voltages, but nominally the same maximum current, then you're fine. Otherwise, you're at best wasting silicon.